# Problem importing XML file with hyphens in element names

Tags: sql-server, xml, import, xsd, bulkinsert

I am pretty new to working with XML/XSD schemas etc. I am trying to use SQLXMLBulkLoad to load an XML file into SQL Server (the file to upload is greater than 2gb) and am having a problem as the source data has element names that contain hyphens, e.g. "first-name" or "start-date".

I have managed to get a few sample records imported into the database excluding those fields, but as soon as I add in any of the elements with a hyphen in the name, the import fails with an error message saying:

> Schema: Invalid Value for 'column', Code: 80004005 Source: Schema Mapping

This only happens when there is a hyphen in an element name and I have no idea how to get around it. I have tried searching for the answer but can't find any reference to the issue I'm having.

The schema code is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">
  <xsd:element name="jobs"  sql:is-constant="1">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="job" sql:relation="mytemptable" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="town" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="start-date" type="xsd:string" />
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I am unable to get the source data file amended to exclude the hyphens so I have to find a way to handle it in the import routine, but I am still not able to get it to work.